# Assuming one does not log out, how long do Facebook OAuth sessions persist? And is it possible to extend this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm looking to use Facebook OAuth and I keep getting logged off every 4 hours.  Not from Facebook.com, but from my site.  Is this typical?  How can I extend this?

Ideally a user should remain auth'd until they log out.

I'm not looking for the deprecated `offline_access`, but rather to allow a user to visit my site today and again tomorrow without having to click the Facebook OAuth button again.  They can always log out manually if they'd like.

Comment: If you embed the JS SDK, it’ll determine the user’s login status for you. Have a look at `FB.getLoginStatus` & co.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An user access token becomes invalid after

- 2 hrs (if generated through client-side flow)
- 2 months (if generated through server-side flow)
- Password change
- De-authorization of app

You can extend the expiry of an access_token(generated through client-side flow) to 60 days by calling this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
        client_id=APP_ID&
        client_secret=APP_SECRET&
        grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
        fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You can learn more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

Once the access_token becomes invalid or expires, you've to make the user follow the login flow again.